# Wait after receiving a Webhook

Tags: php, webhooks

After some research, I haven't found anwers for what I'm trying to achieve.
I found some information about the php sleep() function, and some inforamtions about CRON jobs, but none of these options seem to solve the problem.

Here is what I try to do : I have a php file which may receive webhooks. I need to wait some time (15 minutes for example) before "reacting" to this webhook. So, basically, my script should : 
1 - receive the webhook (Already done with current code)
2 - wait some time
3 - do some actions (Already done)

I've already done what I needed without the wait part, and it works very well, bu now I don't know how to do with it...

If I understood it well, Cron Jobs are executed periodically, while I want to wait some time only when the webhook is received. 
I thought about the sleep() function, but I'm afraid it may use to much ressources...

How can I do this ?

Update : It seems I can't use the sleep function more than 30 seconds (max execution time I guess ?)

Comment: I think that the sleep function is actually what you need

Comment: Thanks. But please see my update : when I use a value over 30 seconds, the end of the scrip is never executed...

Comment: You can also use the time() function to store the time you got your webhook. then use something like while(time() < t+minutes*60). But I don't know about the efficiency. The method doing this would of course be stuck for several minutes

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try. I think it's not the best option for the efficiency, but if it does the job it may be a good begining.

Comment: Just saw H2ONOCK's answer below and it makes a lot more sense. I think that it is the correct way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was you, I'd build a queueing system so that when a webhook comes in, a row in a database is inserted. I'd add a column for 'execution_time' and set that to 15 mins from when the webhook came in. You can then setup a cron job that runs every minute but only fires where the execution_time is 'now'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain a little bit more how you'd do this ? Especially the cron job part... (I mean, running it every minute will use a lot of resources, won't it ?) Anyway thanks, it seems to be the best option...

Comment: It won't use anything near the resources that holding multiple instances of the same script in memory for 15 minutes at a time before execution will. Running Cron Jobs every minute is very normal. I can't really give any more explanation without knowing what your webhook does.

Comment: Ok, this is what I needed to hear (well, to read in facts...). I'll give it a try asap, thanks a lot !

Comment: No worries. If this is closed, don't forget to accept my answer :)

Comment: It wasn't easy, but finally it works perfectly. Many thanks ! Accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

**use cron**

“At every 15th minute past every hour.”

```
Minute  Hour  Day  Month  Weekday  Command  

15      *     *    *      *        php /homelink/path/filename.php
```

**Note:**

You can set an email address for the cron. Every trigger it will send an email notification. If receive email means cron is working, If not then need to check your code. Also you can debug using the appropriate echo's.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but won't it be executed every hour, even if no webhook is received ? And what if I receive a webhook 1 minute before the scheduled time ?